# About a trace inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

If $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain, $u$ satisfies $u\cdot n=0$ and $\nabla\times u=0$ on the boundary, how to prove the following trace inequality:

$$||u||_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}^2\leq C||\nabla u||_{L^2(\Omega)} ||u||_{L^2(\Omega)}$$

It is an inequality in P.L.Lions' book. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Please provide some more details. You certainly need some regularity of the boundary to take traces. Moreover, $\nabla \times u$ is not well-defined on the boundary for functions in $H^1(\Omega)$.